# What's wrong with my Google Docs script for multiple search and replace (replace table)

Tags: replace, google-docs

I was trying to use a Google Docs script for a multiple search & replace. The idea is that words in a given column are replaced with words specified in a 'replace table', possibly consisting of two different columns in the very same, opened spreadsheet. I post the code below. The script runs fine (without errors). The only problem is - absolutely nothing changes, the words are not replaced. What's wrong?

```
function replMyText() {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Lista');
    var rgtxt=sh.getRange('B1:B17'); //text to replace
    var rgrep=sh.getRange('C1:D2'); //replacement table
    var txtA=rgtxt.getValues();
    var repA=rgrep.getValues();
    for(var i=0; i<txtA.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<repA.length; j++) {
            if(txtA[i][0]==repA[j][0]) {
                txtA[i][0]=repA[j][1];
            }
        }
    }
    rgtxt.setValues(txtA);
}
```